# MVC model conflict using partial class and Validate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, partial-views

I have a page containing a form and a partial view (containing a form too).
both model have 1 (or more) properties with the same name. when I validate the first form, the value and validation message is duplicate on the second form.

---

I create a little sample with dummy entities.

person.cs

```
public partial class Person : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "name required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {

        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        if (Name == "admin") //just example
        {
            results.Add(new ValidationResult("You cant be admin.", new[] { "Title", "Name" }));
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

Person/Index.cshtml

```
@model Person
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Person";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Person", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "CreatePersonForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
}

@Html.Partial("~/Views/Dog/Index.cshtml", new Dog())

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

PersonController.cs

```
 public class PersonController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Person
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Index([Bind(Include = "Name")] Person person)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(person);
        }

    }
```

I made a partial view practically the same.

Dog.cs

```
public partial class Dog : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "name required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {

        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        if (Name == "admin") //just example
        {
            results.Add(new ValidationResult("You cant be admin.", new[] { "Title", "Name" }));
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

Dog/Index.cshtml

```
@model Dog
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Dog Page";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Dog", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "CreateDogForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
}


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

DogController.cs

```
 public class DogController : Controller
{
    // GET: Dog
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index([Bind(Include = "Name")] Dog dog)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(dog);
    }

}
```

if you start /Person/Index, if you write admin in the first textbox (person form), after posting (save) the second form (dog form) have the same text and validation than the first form.

[image: first view before action]

[image: write information and save]

[image: result with duplication information]

Comment: Hm maybe this problem goes away if the model passed to the partial is part of the main model. `@Html.Partial("~/Views/Dog/Index.cshtml", Model.Dog)`. I assume this because MVC generates different names and ids for sub-properties of a model, e.g. `Dog_Id` instead of 'Id'.

Comment: so what are you expecting you have same implementation of `IValidateObject` for both

Comment: I just didnt change the implementation for each validation. shouldn't be exactly the same.

Comment: Georg, I was hopping to not change every id as first option. I was hoping there's something about model or form that I didnt understand.

Comment: The issue is that you have duplicate name attributes. But your view makes  no sense (you can only submit one form at a time) so are your just wanting to understand the issue, or do you really want to create that view (and if so why)?

Comment: the other view in my "real" site is in a model window.

Comment: I maybe found the solution (still testing), I use Html.Action instead of Html.Partial.

Answer (score 0):

The `@Html.EditorFor` by default uses the property name as the `id` and `name` of the generated `HTML`, and the validation uses these values to set the error messages! You can pass a value to overwrite that default behavior in your partial view as following:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @data_valmsg_for="partial_name"  })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id="partial_name" } })
```

Comment: `data_valmsg_for` refers the the controls `name` attribute so this will not work (and in any case its too late - the error has already need added when the view is returned - that attribute is only for use by `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`

Comment: Exactly, so when the view is rendered the error message for the first name won't affect the second :)

Comment: I take it you did not understand my comment - this does **not** work